# How do you unit test Scala in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, scala, junit

I am learning Scala and would like to set up integrated unit testing in Eclipse.
As far as I can tell from googling, ScalaTest is the way to go, possibly in combination with JUnit.

What are your experiences with unit testing Scala in Eclipse? Should I use the JUnit runner or something else?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but there's some documentation here: https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Using_Unit_Testing_Frameworks

Comment: @Matt Thanks, this works - you should add it as an answer, actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to keep the answers up to date: ScalaTest now comes with an [eclipse plugin](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_eclipse), which should handle running tests from Eclipse out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 7):

There is a wiki page on the ScalaIDE website on [how to run Scala unit tests in Eclipse](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Using_Unit_Testing_Frameworks). If you have specific issues with running specs unit tests, I encourage you to post messages on the [specs-users](http://groups.google.com/group/specs-users) mailing list.

Eric.

Comment: If mailing lists were sufficient for everybody then the world would have no need of Stack Overflow

Comment: I agree, not a very helpful answer by myself :-)

Answer (score 6):

I was unable to run the ScalaTest specs with JUnit runner inside eclipse. I think this is because of the absence of the `@Test` annotated methods. However if your project has Maven support, you can run your specs from command line using `mvn test`. For Surefire plugin to detect your specs, use the following configuration in your pom file.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <configuration>
   <includes>
    <include>**/*Spec.class</include>
   </includes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Check out [these example](http://github.com/abhin4v/spelhelper/tree/master/src/test/scala/net/abhinavsarkar/spelhelper/) for reference.

Comment: This has been improved - see @Eric's answer for a pointer to the website: http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Using_Unit_Testing_Frameworks

Answer (score 2):

I've spent the past few days trying to find a combination of unit tests that work with scala for my project and this is what I've found.

I am using the release candidates for Scala 2.8 because it fixes a number of bugs that were blocking me in 2.7.2.  I initially tried to get Scalatest to work with 2.8, but was unable to find a stable solution, in the future that may be a better way to go, but currently there appears to be too much in flux around the 2.8 release.

The configuration I have working is to use JUnit4 annotations in my scala test code like so:

```
import org.junit._

import Assert._

class TestSuite{

  @Test def testSimple(){ 
    asserEquals("Equal",1,1)
  }
}
```

Then I am using a java JUnit test suite to run all my tests together like so:

```
import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses( { 
  TestSuite.class
  })
public class AllTests {

  public static Test suite() {
    TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("Test Suite");
    return suite;
  }

}
```

The only additional trick is to add the output directory as a source directory in Eclipse so that the JUnit runner can find your class files.  This is a bit of a hack, but it seems to work.

Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Source->Add Folder and then click on classes (or bin, wherever you are compiling your class files to).

This runs fine in Eclipse by right clicking on AllTests.java and selecting RunAs->Junit

Comment: I found out that I could just right-click on a scala file containing annotated test code and pick RunAs->Junit, provided that I had added the library reference for JUnit.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to work for me too, though for my project running a full suite of tests is more useful. It did not work when I tried to create a .scala file with the JUnit4 annotations to create a suite of my tests.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get unit tests running from Eclipse either (admittedly I didn't try too hard), but if you're willing to take a look at IntelliJ ScalaTest works from within the IDE with no problems.

Comment: It turned out that the JUnit runner worked for me out of the box in Eclipse. I just had to import the right package and write @test before the test methods, just like in Java. Haven't tried ScalaTest yet though.

Comment: I highly recommend using IntelliJ, when I started out unit testing with scala (http://www.persistentpanda.com/2011/03/unit-testing-with-scala.html), the only thing Eclipse gave me was a headache. Especially with Maven projects.